# Column and rowspan problem in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to change the rowspan, columnspan properties of a control(textbox) when they
are within a TableLayoutPanel (net 2008 using c# or vb.net)

At runtime the property is not available, but is at design time

Any ideas

Answer (score 3):

use TableLayoutPanel.SetRowSpan, and TableLayoutPanel.SetColumnSpan Methods:

Example:

```
TableLayoutPanel1.SetRowSpan(textbox1, 2);
```

this will set the rowspan of the textbox to 2;